# Proving $aH=bH\iff b\in aH$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $a,b\in G$ and $H\leq G$ 
>   Prove: for all $a,b$ $$aH=bH\iff b\in aH$$

$\Rightarrow:$ $$b=be\in bH=aH $$

$\Leftarrow:$ $$b=be\in bH$$ On the other hand
$$b\in aH$$

And therefore $$b\in  aH\cap bH\iff aH=bH$$ as cosets are either equal or disjoint.

Is it valid?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Good job! (Assuming that "cosets are equal or disjoint" is a result you have access to; there is some danger of this proof being circular, since the result you want to show seems like a great lemma to prove that cosets are equal or disjoint)

Comment: To avoid a circular argument, maybe you can argue like this: if $b \in aH$ there exists $h \in H$ such that $b = ah$. Then $bk = a(hk) \in aH$ for any $k \in H$, that is $bH \subseteq aH$. On the other hand, $a = bh^{-1}$, so $ak = b(h^{-1}k) \in bH$ for any $k \in H$. Therefore $aH \subseteq bH$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is valid. Well done. You need to assume, though, that $$xH\cap yH\neq\varnothing \iff xH=yH\tag{1}$$ for all $x,y\in G$.

A proof given in Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"* goes as follows, *mutatis mutandis.*

If $aH=bH$, then $b=be\in bH=aH$.

If $b\in aH$, then $b=ah$ for some $h\in H$. Therefore, $$\begin{align}
bH&=(ah)H \\
&=a(hH)\\
&=aH.
\end{align}$$

This follows directly from associativity of the group operation and does not rely on $(1)$.